# Qual è l'origine dell'espressione "... non mangiare il panettone"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Domanda natalizia.

In gergo calcistico, spesso si sente dire:

*L'allenatore XY non mangerà il panettone*

nel senso che sarà esonerato prima di Natale, per gli scarsi risultati ottenuti con la squadra all'inizio del campionato.

L'espressione è entrata nel linguaggio comune,  ad esempio prima del referendum si poteva dire:

*Se vince il "no", mi sa che il governo Renzi non arriva a mangiare il panettone*.

Qual è l'origine di questo modo di dire? Chi l'ha utilizzato per primo?

Buon Natale a tutti!

Comment: cito da Wikipedia (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_delle_frasi_fatte):
_"Voce di origine probabilmente milanese, in tempi in cui gli incarichi avevano spesso scadenza annuale alla fine dell'anno solare: non arrivare a mangiare il panettone significa quindi avere scadenza anticipata rispetto al previsto."_
Ma non so da dove arrivi...

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Visto che si parla di panettone, è probabile che sia milanese! Ahahah

Answer (score 2):

Se non ricordo male, l'Inter ha la tradizione di organizzare una festa di Natale, nella quale l'allenatore viene fotografato mentre mangia il panettone. Pertanto, se questo viene esonerato prima della pausa natalizia "non arriva a mangiare il panettone".

Dovrebbe essere questa l'origine dell'espressione

Comment: Grazie, non lo sapevo anche se sono (molto vagamente) interista... visto quanti allenatori cambiano è probabile che l'origine sia questa :)

Comment: Una risposta così (“se non ricordo male... dovrebbe essere”) non è molto utile. Riesci a trovare qualche fonte? Se no, domani può arrivare qualcun altro e raccontare lo stesso del Milan o dell'Atalanta.

Comment: È una memoria che risale ad un documentario sulla Grande Inter, ma non saprei dove trovarlo, ora come ora. Farò qualche ricerca